# Unable to install Django with pipenv even though pipenv appears to be installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pip, pipenv

I'm using Python 3.8.1:

```sh
$ python -V
Python 3.8.1
```

I've installed pipenv:

```sh
$ pip list | grep pipenv
pipenv                         2018.11.26
```

If I try to install Django I get the following error:

```sh
$ pipenv install django
pyenv: pipenv: command not found

The `pipenv' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.7.2
```

Have I done something wrong that causes pipenv to not work with 3.8.1 and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a pipenv user, but it seems that your pipenv have been installed with python 3.7.2 on your system, rather than the default python 3.8.1.

This may due to your pip in env is actually for python 3.7.2 on your system.

One possible Solution:

1. Uninstall pipenv installed with with python 3.7.2

```
   pip uninstall pipenv
```

2. install pipenv with python 3.8.1

```
   python -m pip install pipenv
```

3. install Django with pipenv

```
   python -m pipenv install django
```